# Marketing Cloud Sync Data Extension with 3rd party system via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

At the moment I try to get data from a 3rd party system into Salesforce (it must be scheduled every 5 hours)

**Is there any way to integrate Data from a 3rd Party system into a DataExtension in SFMC?**

I thought i can go with FTP solution but im not sure if and how i should get the data from 3rd party system in a csv fiel and upload it.

**Is there any other way e.g using the API to update a DataExtension in SFMC with customer data from 3rd Party systems?**

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so other users can see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Marketing Cloud REST-API for example. The call [PUT /hub/v1/dataevents/key:{key}/rows/{primaryKeys}](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/putDataExtensionRowByKey.htm) can be used to insert and update an entry in a dataextension. In addition there is also another route that allows you to upsert multiple rows at once: [POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key:{key}/rowset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm)

**An example request for upserting a singe record could look like this:**

*Headers*

> Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
>
> PUT /hub/v1/dataevents/11954DDF-28A3-4FE8-BF77-646C37506621/rows/Email:someone@exacttarget.com
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

*Payload:*

```
{
    "values":{
            "LastLogin": "2013-05-23T14:32:00Z",
            "IsActive": true,
            "FirstName": "John",
            "FollowerCount": 2,
            "LastName": "Smith"
     }
}
```